# Items in datalist as side-by-side

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I am trying to set the items from my datalist side by side. The items at the moment do appear side-by-side but the second appears about 30 pixels lower than the first, and the third about 30 pixels lower than the second. Any ideas how to force them align horizontally in a nice way?

My style:

```
.wrapping {
    float: left;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-style: dashed;
}
  #boxer {
    /* basic */
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 60px;
    text-align: center; /* border-radius */
}
```

My list:

```
<asp:DataList ID="myDataList" runat="server" BorderColor="Black" CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatLayout="Flow">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="wrapping">  
        <div id="boxer" >
              <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/topimages/" & Eval("ImageName") %>' cssclass="topimage" />
                <br /><br />
                ProductID:<asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
                <br />Name:<asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName")%>' />
                <br />
        </div>
    </div>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: have you tried to give the `.wrapping` a `vertical-align:top;` ?

Comment: @Paul yes, that was my first thought but didn't work.

Comment: I put your code into a JSfiddle, I didn't get the problem you have, so it probably doesn't have anything to do with the code you provided.
http://jsfiddle.net/okn6z26a/

Answer (score 0):

After I added  `RepeatDirection="Horizontal"` in the DataList it worked as expected.